# Выполнение php скрипта, при нажатии на ссылку

Tags: php

Доброго дня. Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли возможность сделать так: при нажатии на ссылку, выполняется php скрипт находящийся тут же, на сервере, но при этом не переходить на сам скрипт. То есть я могу по ссылке перейти на test.php, но нужно чтобы я остался на текущей странице..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете повесить на ссылку событие, которое отправить аяксом или постом запрос на выполнение вашего php скрипта

Comment: Не подскажите как?

Comment: Желательно второй случай, с аяксом не знаком совершенно.

Comment: Для Вас слово "аяксом" === "отправить методом GET"?

Comment: @istimbi, второго случая нет. Придется изучить аякс.

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ - использовать ajax, для этого необходимо всего-лишь подключить jquery и разобраться с параметрами его функции $.ajax().
Например, нам надо что бы при клике на ссылку с ID="some_link" мы спрашивали что-то у скрипта ajax.php, добавляем на страницу следующий js код:

```
$('#some_link').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: /ajax.php,
        success: function(response) { alert(response); }
     });
});
```